# Exception: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, sqlite

So I just faced this problem yesterday when I uninstalled and reinstalled my App to check that permissions are requested correctly.

Before that the app was working fine, but now I cannot get anything from my database. I always get this error when trying to get data from Cursor.

```
Process: com.example.asusx556u.myapplication, PID: 1720
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asusx556u.myapplication/com.example.asusx556u.myapplication.RingtonesPlayLists}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
at com.example.asusx556u.myapplication.RingtonesPlayLists.checkRingtones(RingtonesPlayLists.java:54)
at com.example.asusx556u.myapplication.RingtonesPlayLists.onCreate(RingtonesPlayLists.java:34)
```

checkRingtones:

```js
public void checkRingtones() {
        if(ringtonesCursor == null) {
            return;
        }

        boolean bModified = false;
        DatabaseHelper ringtonesDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        if(ringtonesCursor.moveToFirst())
            Log.v("SL", "Moved successfully to first row.");
        do {
            File ringtoneFile = new File(ringtonesCursor.getString(2));
            if(!ringtoneFile.exists()) {
                bModified = true;
                ringtonesDB.delete(ringtonesCursor.getInt(0));
                Log.e("SL", "Ringtone \"" + ringtonesCursor.getString(2) +
                "\" cannot be found and therefore will be deleted!");
            }
        } while (ringtonesCursor.moveToNext());

        if(bModified)
            getRingtones();
    }
```

getRingtones:

```js
public void getRingtones() {
        DatabaseHelper ringtonesDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        ringtonesCursor = ringtonesDB.getAll();
    }
```

database.getAll:

```js
public Cursor getAll() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = _openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return db.rawQuery("select * from RINGTONES_LITE order by _id", null);
    }
```

database.onCreate:

```js
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("create table RINGTONES_LITE (_id integer primary key autoincrement, NAME text, URI text unique)");
        }
```

Comment: Your code writes to the `Log`. That information would have been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely due to there being no check for an empty Cursor so the Cursor has 0 rows and thus no columns ( i.e offset 0 ) from which to get any data from.

This is because the check for the Cursor being null serves no purpose. If the Cursor has no rows the Cursor will be empty not null (the Cursor `getCount()` method will return 0).

The check that could detect this, the `moveToFirst` (will return false if the Cursor has no rows). Is limited only to the Log statement. The do clause is still entered and thus the result that there is no offset 0 as there are no rows.

A fix could be to use :-

```
public void checkRingtones() {

    boolean bModified = false;
    DatabaseHelper ringtonesDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    while(ringtoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
        File ringtoneFile = new File(ringtonesCursor.getString(2));
        if(!ringtoneFile.exists()) {
            bModified = true;
            ringtonesDB.delete(ringtonesCursor.getInt(0));
            Log.e("SL", "Ringtone \"" + ringtonesCursor.getString(2) +
            "\" cannot be found and therefore will be deleted!");
        }
    }

    if(bModified)
        getRingtones();
}
```

Or alternately :-

```
public void checkRingtones() {
    if(ringtonesCursor.getCount() < 1) {
        return;
    }

    boolean bModified = false;
    DatabaseHelper ringtonesDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    if(ringtonesCursor.moveToFirst())
        Log.v("SL", "Moved successfully to first row.");
    do {
        File ringtoneFile = new File(ringtonesCursor.getString(2));
        if(!ringtoneFile.exists()) {
            bModified = true;
            ringtonesDB.delete(ringtonesCursor.getInt(0));
            Log.e("SL", "Ringtone \"" + ringtonesCursor.getString(2) +
            "\" cannot be found and therefore will be deleted!");
        }
    } while (ringtonesCursor.moveToNext());

    if(bModified)
        getRingtones();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what caused the problem. I thought that a Cursor is null when empty which wasn't true obviously. Thank you for your answer!